# What are the parentheses used for in a bash shell script function definition like "f () {}"? Is it different than using the "function" keyword?

Tags: linux, bash, function, parentheses

I'v always wondered what they're used for?
Seems silly to put them in every time if you can never put anything inside them.

```
function_name () {
    #statements
}
```

Also is there anything to gain/lose with putting the `function` keyword at the start of a function?

```
function function_name () {
    #statements
}
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The keyword `function` has been deprecated in favor of `function_name()` for portability with the [**POSIX spec**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_05)

> A function is a user-defined name that
>   is used as a simple command to call a
>   compound command with new positional
>   parameters. A function is defined with
>   a "function definition command".
>
> The format of a function definition
>   command is as follows:
>
> ```
> fname() compound-command[io-redirect ...]
> ```

Note that the `{ }` are not mandatory so if you're not going to use the keyword `function` (and you shouldn't) then the `()` are necessary so the parser knows you're defining a function.

Example, this is a legal function definition and invocation:

```
$ myfunc() for arg; do echo "$arg"; done; myfunc foo bar
foo
bar
```

Comment: What about without parenthesis? I've seen `function myfunc {` before.

Comment: @AaronFranke Just another way to do a function definition, although I’ll say that way is less widely used.

Answer (score 14):

The empty parentheses are required in your first example so that bash knows it's a function definition (otherwise it looks like an ordinary command). In the second example, the `()` is optional because you've used `function`.

Comment: Ah ok, guess that makes sense, it's just in PHP you can put stuff inside the parentheses, so I was curious wether I could do something similar in linux scripting.

Comment: @Mint: You can't put anything inside the parentheses and they're not used when calling the function, but you can still pass positional parameters to the function. `foo () { echo "$1"; }; foo hello`

Answer (score 7):

**Without `function`, alias expansion happens at definition time**. E.g.:

```
alias a=b
# Gets expanded to "b() { echo c; }" :
a() { echo c; }
b
# => c
# Gets expanded to b:
a
# => c
```

With `function` however, alias expansion does not happen at definition time, so the alias "hides" the definition:

```
alias a=b
function a { echo c; }
b
# => command not found
# Gets expanded to b:
a
# => command not found
unalias a
a
# => c
```

Comment: This isn't a feature of the `function` keyword -- it's just aliases working the way they always do, performing textual replacement *on the first word in a line* alone. If someone had created an alias named `function`, it would still be expanded here.