# I want to take in using the user's input, then call a function using a case statement

Tags: bash

I'm working within bash and I'm struggling to take the user's input then move them into a function. I'm using a case statement to get it to work and this is the code I'm currently working with:

```
read -n1 -p "Save to log? [y,n] " choice \n
case $choice in
    y|Y) echo yes ;;
    n|N) echo no ;;
    *) echo dont know ;;
esac

function saveToLog(){
    echo Saving to log
}
```

And i've tried what I thought would work here:

```
read -n1 -p "Save to log? [y,n] " choice \n
case $choice in
    y|Y) saveToLog() ;;
    n|N) echo no ;;
    *) echo dont know ;;
esac

function saveToLog(){
    echo Saving to log
}
```

But that doesn't work, I've done some googling and I can't find a solution using a case statement as I'd like to keep using this system.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for the `()` behind `saveToLog`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

read -n1 -p "Save to log? [y,n] " choice \n
case $choice in
    y|Y) saveToLog ;;
    n|N) echo "no" ;;
    *) echo "dont know" ;;
esac

function saveToLog(){
    echo "Saving to log"
}
```

Will call `saveToLog` on `y|Y`

---

**Note**: `saveToLog` must be delared as it is (using the `function` keyword) for this to work. Please take a look at [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654700/what-are-the-parentheses-used-for-in-a-bash-shell-script-function-definition-lik) for more information about `function` and `()`

Comment: Oh I didn't know that you could call a function in bash like that! I'm used to standard coding conventions in other languages, thank you!

Comment: In the shell, functions (and aliases) are intended to look to the user just like any other command.